# Windows Service can't access network

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, administration, windows-server

I installed windows service. It runs under my special predefined account. And it can't access network anyway. If I run my console application with the same code under this account it can access network successfully.
Now I am trying to run this code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

It works fine in Console Application but does not work in windows service.
I believe that I should grant some special rights to my account to allow it to access the internet from the windows service. Could you advice me which rights shoud I set?

Comment: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out<br/>
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)<br/>
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)<br/>
   at MyClass.Run() in C:\Projects\MyProg\MyClass.cs:line 33

Comment: What do you mean by "my special predefined account"? Also, how are you checking whether the download is working?

Comment: Did you try to run the service with some standard account (network service/ local service)?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, my special predefined account - domain windows account which is intended specially for running this service. I check that download works by the following line of code. In console it is Console.Writeline, in windows service it is write to log.

Comment: Ikaso, no I didn't. But it's necessary for me to use the separate account for windows service.

Comment: So, if you use `RUNAS` to run the console application under the service user account, does it work? (By the way, you need to put `@` before people's usernames if you're replying to them and you want them to be notified about your comment)

Comment: I've run in to this a few times before too and I'll be damned if I can figure out what's causing it.  Every once in a while when I restart my Windows 8.1 box, none of my Windows Services can access the internet.  Internet from the desktop works just fine though.  After rebooting a few times it comes back up.